# Coorect size of UImage and UIImageView with iphone 6 and 6s

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

I am coming back to ios after some break. My designer does the wireframing in iphone 6 screen size. Now I have the img@2x.png of size 120*120(w*h) . I used to create UIImageView of 60*60 before and it would render for retina and non-retina correctly.

Question :

```
1. what should be the size of UIImageView to accommodate that image?
2. is 180*180 the correct size for img@3x.png.
```

Comment: 1)  UIImageView size should be 60x60. and 2) Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

The @3x size is 3 times the size in non-retina display. In your case 60x60 * 3 = 180 x 180.

Keep in mind that the @3x image is used only in the iPhone 6 Plus, because the iPhone 6 will render (and accommodate) the @2x image to the wider screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support non-retina devices then you should have a 60x60 image as well, named "img.png".

1. the UIImageView size should be 60x60
2. the @3x image should be triple the size of the non-retina image. For this case it would be 180x180